Writing debezium CDC events from Kafka Connect to Iceberg
We want to ingest Debezium CDC events into Iceberg Tables on Azure Blob. We aim to do so using Kafka Connect Iceberg Sink Connector, and a Snowflake Catalog for Iceberg.
Questions that have surfaced -

Can Avro file types be inserted into Iceberg tables?

If 'yes' to 1, are further operations required if we want to query Iceberg tables as columnar-based, parquet files

If 'no' to 1, which alternatives exist for capturing CDC into Iceberg as parquet files?


We have tried researching a variety of approaches - thanks in advance for your help.
